# Pass data variable frrom PHP to MYSQL procedure

Tags: php, mysql

These are the variables in PHP:

```
$MON = "2017-06-21";
$TUE = "2017-06-22";
$WED = "2017-06-23";
$THU = "2017-06-24";
$FRI = "2017-06-25";
```

When I use this statement the procedure works fine:

```
$query = "call FSS.GetWeeklySched('2017-06-21', '2017-06-22', '2107-06-23', '2017-06-24', '2107-06-25');";
```

However, when I try it with variables like this it doesn't work:

```
query =  "call FSS.GetWeeklySched($MON, $TUE, $WED, $THU, $FRI)";
```

I am sure that I am not doing it correctly. I've tried many combinations.

Comment: In your second line you don't have a dollar sign. Is this just a typo? Do you get any error messages in either PHP or SQL?

Comment: Try echo $query and paste the result please

Comment: Oops. Just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use this form - better readability and delimitation of the strings concatenation - and add "$" at the beginning of the variable name "query":

```
$query = "call FSS.GetWeeklySched(" . $MON . "," . $TUE . "," . $WED . "," . $THU . "," . $FRI . ");";
```

Comment: Yes, I know. @R.A.Munna's answer is your answer why my answer is not working ;-) And don't forget to correct with the "$".

Comment: I tried several variations of this and still no results.

Comment: @cxxxv You missed the semicolon ";" at the end of your call. That must be the problem then!

Comment: @cxxxv R.A.Munna's answer is correspondingly reedited.

Comment: @cxxxv Well, I'm glad that it works. The code which R.A.Munna presented is the same as your solution, but making the use of the concatenation operator (.). Personally, I recommend you to begin using this form. It gives you a better delimitation of the server side vars, e.g a better readability. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use it in this way

```
$query =  "call FSS.GetWeeklySched('".$MON."', '".$TUE."',  '".$WED."' ,'".$THU."', '".$FRI."');";
```

Comment: `query` => `$query` ;-)

Comment: got it. Thanks :)

Comment: `... "')";` => `... "');";` ;-)

Comment: I learned to never promise such a thing when it goes to dev. So... til later :-D :-D